# Linux Bash Shell Custom Error Message

Tags: bash, error-handling, custom-error-handling

I'm trying to spew a custom error message using the following 1 liner bash shell command.  I'm not getting the "errorMessage" var set.  However if I run the command individually, I'm able to capture the error message into $errorMessage variable. **What am I missing?**

**Command:**

```
[ "errorMessage=$(mkdir -p /path/to/restricted/folder 2>&1)" ] && echo "Something Went Wrong; Error is: ${errorMessage}"
```

**Trials/Output:**

```
$ [ "errorMessage=$(mkdir -p /path/to/restricted/folder 2>&1)" ] && echo "Something Went Wrong; Error is: ${errorMessage}"
Something Went Wrong; Error is:
$ echo $errorMessage

$ errorMessage=$(mkdir -p /path/to/restricted/folder 2>&1)
$ echo $errorMessage
mkdir: cannot create directory `/path': Permission denied
```

Comment: BTW -- looking at it, this is a quite well-asked question, moreso than is often the case for someone new to the site. Thank you for taking the time to make it easy to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[` is the command named `test`; when not given an argument specifying an individual test to run, the default is `-n` (testing whether a string is empty). This code is testing whether the string `"errorMessage="` (possibly with a suffix from the stderr of `mkdir`) is empty or not; since it contains a fixed prefix, it will **never** be empty, whether any error was emitted or not.

If you want to actually assign a value to the variable, that would instead look like:

```
errorMessage=$(mkdir -p /path/to/restricted/folder 2>&1) \
  || echo "Something Went Wrong; Error is: ${errorMessage}"
```

This is checking the *exit status* of `mkdir`, and running the `echo` should that be nonzero.